# how to validate two checkbox in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two check boxes with different name and id and I want the users to check at least one of them if not the button will disable! but if one of them checked it will proceed to the other file

```js
function validate(){
var time12 = document.getElementById("time12").checked;
var time24 = document.getElementById("time24").checked;

if((time12 == "") && ( time24 == "") )
{
 alert("Choose your hour rate");
 return false;
}
 return true;
}
```

```html
   

<input id="time12"  type="checkbox" name="time12" value="12"   />12hours
<input id="time24"  type="checkbox" name="time24" value="24"   />24hours
```

but before you type your hate comments I want you to inform that I already search about it and I don't have the same question like this!

or suggest me other way thank you in advance

Comment: What button should get disabled? I see only two check-boxes. I see the validation method but nothing that triggers it.

Comment: im sorry i was too late to realize that i forgot to add my button... <input type="submit" value="FORM 3"   name="btn_form3" >

Comment: you edited my question first before me so that i cant change my question haha sorry :(

Comment: See answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `onclick()` with your function.

```js
function validate(){
var time12 = document.getElementById("time12").checked;
var time24 = document.getElementById("time24").checked;

if((time12 == "") && ( time24 == "") )
{
 alert("Choose your hour rate");
 return false;
}
 return true;
}
```

```html
<input id="time12"  type="checkbox" name="time12" value="12"   />12hours
<input id="time24"  type="checkbox" name="time24" value="24"   />24hours

<button onclick="validate()" >submit</button>
```

Comment: According to the post, some button should get disabled

Comment: but is it possible to put this in my PHP file?
because I have two number attributes and if this two numbers have a same variable i want to disable the  <input id="time24"  type="checkbox" name="time24" value="24"   />24hours

Comment: this number attributes        <Input id="chiD" name="chiD" type="number" min="<?php echo $_SESSION["day_today"]; ?>" max="<?php echo $_SESSION["day_count"]; ?>" value = "<?php $_SESSION["chiD"] ?>" required> is from file one this is the fiirst number

Comment: and this one is the second one from file 2.php <Input id="choD" name=" choD" type="number" min="<?php echo $_SESSION["day_todayz"]; ?>" max="<?php echo $_SESSION["day_countz"]; ?>"  required>

Comment: I haven't dealt with php too much, but I'm sure you can added to your php file.  You should write another question for the php.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is every time a checkbox is checked, you want to see if both checkboxes are currently checked.

To do this its something like

```
$( "input:checkbox" ).on("change", function(){
   var checked = false;
   if($("#input1).prop("checked"))
      checked = true;
   if($("#input2).prop("checked"))
      checked = true;
   if(!checked)
      button.prop("disabled",true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To make this work you need to attach an event handler to the `change` event of the checkboxes. You can then enable/disable the button based on the checked state of the elements. Try this:

```js
$('.hours').change(function() {
   $('#btn').prop('disabled', !$('.hours:checked').length);
}).change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
  <input id="time12" type="checkbox" name="time12" value="12" class="hours" />
  12hours
</label>
<label>
  <input id="time24" type="checkbox" name="time24" value="24" class="hours" />
  24hours
</label>
<input type="submit" value="FORM 3" name="btn_form3" id="btn" />
```

Note that I added a class of `hours` to the checkboxes and an id of `#btn` to the button, simply to make selecting the elements easier.

Answer (score 0):

See this example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bRXMpx

```
<script>
function validate(){
var time12 = document.getElementById("time12").checked;
var time24 = document.getElementById("time24").checked;

if((time12 == "") && ( time24 == "") )
{
    document.getElementById("btn").disabled = true;
    alert("Choose your hour rate");
    return false;
}
else
document.getElementById("btn").disabled = false;
    return true;
}
</script>
<html>
<input id="time12"  type="checkbox" onclick="validate()" name="time12" value="12"   />12hours
<input id="time24"  type="checkbox" onclick="validate()" name="time24" value="24"   />24hours
<input type="submit" id="btn" value="FORM 3" onclick="validate()" name="btn_form3" > 
</html>
```